# Basic Topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Given $a \neq b$ at $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ determine $c$ in $[ab]$ such that $c \bot (b-a)$. Conclude that for all $ x \in [ab]$, $x \neq c$ $|c| < |x|$.

Okay, I could find the form of $c$, if $\langle c,b-a\rangle=0$ and $c = a + t(b-a)$ for $t \in[0,1]$ then $t_{0}=\dfrac{\langle a,b-a\rangle}{|b-a|^{2}}$ but how can i prove that for all $x = a + t(b-a)$ we have $|c| < |x|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that $c$ is the unique, i.e., if $c' \in [ab]$ and $\langle c',b-a\rangle= 0$, then $c'=c$.

Now take $x = a + t(b-a)$. If $x \neq c$, then $\langle a+t(b-a), b-a\rangle\neq0$ (Since $c$ is unique).

Finally compute $\langle x,x\rangle^{2}$ and compare to $\langle c,c\rangle^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can improve the question a little bit showing the following proposition.

> Let $E$ be an inner product space. If $u,v,w\in E$ (with $u\neq v$) then exist a point $x\in E$ on the line $[uv]$ an element such that $|x-w|<|y-w|$ for every other point $y\in[uv]$.

Let's write $|x-w|^2$ as a single variable function. Then, 
\begin{align*}
f(t)&=|x-w|^2=|(u+t(v-u))-w|^2=|(u-w)+t(v-u)|^2\\
&=|u-w|^2+2t\langle u-w,v-u\rangle+t^2|v-u|^2.
\end{align*}
Note this is a quadratic function and since $|v-u|>0$ we have that $f$ attains an absolute minimum when 
$$t=-\dfrac{2\langle u-w,v-u\rangle}{2|u-w|^2}=\dfrac{\langle w-u,v-u\rangle}{|u-w|^2}.$$